# Create multiple input elements using single class in WTForms (Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am making a web app in Flask to generate XML to be imported into Excel. The web app has a form where there are 15 questions, 4 options for the questions, correct answer and a timer.

Here is my `forms.py` which is using WTForms:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

class XMLQuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    question = StringField('Question', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=395)])
    optionA = StringField('Option A', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)])
    optionB = StringField('Option B', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)])
    optionC = StringField('Option C', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)])
    optionD = StringField('Option D', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=85)])
    answer = SelectField('Answer', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('Option A','Option B','Option C','Option D')])
    timer = IntegerField('Timer', default=60)
```

Now, I want to create an HTML file where 15 different questions, options and answer for each of these can be entered and submitted. After submission, I will handle it in `routes.py`

Here is my `routes.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from myflaskapp import app

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home",)
def home():
    form = XMLQuestionForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #Do something
    else:
        flash('ERROR MESSAGE', 'danger')
    return render_template('home.html', title='Questions XML Form', form=form)
```

I want to have 15 such fields as I mentioned above without having to create multiple form class variables.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reserve judgement on the efficiency or appropriateness of this approach but one may of doing it is being a factory function:

```
def create_form(input):
    class Form(FlaskForm):
        timer = IntegerField('Timer', default=60)

    kwargs = {'validators': [DataRequired(), Length(max=85)]}
    for i, vals in enumerate(input):
        setattr(Form, 'questn_' + str(i), StringField(vals[0], **kwargs))
        setattr(Form, 'answer_' + str(i), StringField(vals[1], **kwargs))
        for j, opt in enumerate(vals[2]):
            setattr(Form, 'opt_' + str(i) + str(j), StringField(opt, **kwargs))
    
    return Form

Form = create_form([
    ['Question1', 'Answer1', ['OptA', 'OptB', 'OptC']],
    ['Question2', 'Answer2', ['OptX', 'OptY']]
])
```